# Can not connect to google cloud sql(second generation) from google app engine(spring boot app)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-boot, google-cloud-sql

It has been driving me crazy recently, Hope anyone can help me on this.

I has been trying to connect to google cloud sql(second generation) from google app engine(spring boot app), but getting no luck. I follow the instruction on this page https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-cloud-sql to get the connection string. it was fine to connect to google cloud sql from my local computer.

Also, my app engine and google sql instance is from the same project. i also verified that i can connect to the google sql from goole app engine's cloud shell

I wonder which is the correct connection string to use. i tried both these connection template, but getting no luck

- "jdbc:google:mysql://${INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}/${database}?user=${user}&password=${password}"
- "jdbc:mysql://google/${database}?useSSL=false&cloudSqlInstance=${INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=${user}&password=${password}"

This is the log trace from google cloud:

```
017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
```

2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]  Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar!/:5.1.43]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar!/:5.1.43]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:341) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar!/:5.1.43]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2196) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar!/:5.1.43]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2229) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar!/:5.1.43]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2024) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar!/:5.1.43]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:779) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar!/:5.1.43]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar!/:5.1.43]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar!/:5.1.43]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar!/:5.1.43]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar!/:5.1.43]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar!/:na]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar!/:na]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar!/:na]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar!/:na]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar!/:na]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.(ConnectionPool.java:154) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar!/:na]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar!/:na]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar!/:na]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar!/:na]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]    ... 29 common frames omitted
2017-11-17 00:20:51 default[20171117t071753]  Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: google      at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1280) ~[na:1.8.0_131]    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192) ~[na:1.8.0_131]     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126) ~[na:1.8.0_131]     at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:188) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar!/:5.1.43]     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:300) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.43.jar!/:5.1.43]

Answer (score 0):

In my application properties I am using jdbc:mysql://[host]:[port]/[dbname]?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false for a url property and it works fine.

But it seems to me that your error is due to fact that you have to authorize IP address of your app-engine in authorization section of your cloud-sql instance.

[Configuring IP Access on Cloud SQL instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ip)

Comment: Thank Pavle for taking time to answer the question. What you has mentioned is if we connect to cloud-sql from external environment.
Also, I just figured out what I have been doing wrong, we has to set packaging to war instead of jar, and add appengine-web.xml to set use-google-connector-j to true, which will instruct google engine to use google connector instead of mysql-connector

Comment: This is incorrect advice. When connecting from App Engine, you should not be connecting by IP but rather using the App Engine specific connectivity as described here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine.